# Creating a log file only when an error or exceptions occured without using log4j

Tags: java, file, exception, logging, error-handling

I want to maintain a log file or txt file ,where I am able to maintain the exception details as well as some other details either in txt or log file.The scenario is like this

```
try {
    .......
} catch(exception e) {
    here the file should be created
}
```

what will be the best optimize solution for this without using logging frameworks.

Could this work for me?

```
try  {
    // something
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(new File("error.log")));
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit further why logging frameworks are out of the question? but well, if you insist on going without them, then you'd need to roll your own. There is no one "best optimize solution".

Comment: what do you mean by elaborate, see I have to just write the exception details into a file when an exception occurs,thats it, is'nt it clear

Comment: I like using a simple FileWriter : construct in the constructor of the class, and just call for each write method in the catch exceptions. Might not be the best way, but it is pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any logging framework, you might look at the [Java Logging Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) and use it to create your own implementation

The [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) contains all required classes that you need for your implementation

Comment: actually, I did'nt use any logging framework in my current project and there is time where i want to create a file when any kind of exceptions are thrown and these exception and some other details are written into a log file, thts why i did'nt use logging

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk - `java.util.logging` is actually a collection of interfaces and classes that will help you provide your own implementation. However this requires that handle all the requirements for your logging implementation

Answer (score 0):

Logging Frameworks are there to help you maintain your log files.

If you don't want to use them, you can design your own logging mechanism with all the pain 
of writing to text file.

In case of log4j:

```
 1. You can set the logging levels like debug,error,info etc...

 2. You can set appenders like File Appender, Console Appender etc..
```

These 2 things might suffice your need.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to run some code that appends the required information to a (log) file. So at the end you will have a *logger* class that provides some static methods like *logException* or *logError*. A trivial draft for this:

```
public class MyLogger {

   public static log(Object sender, Throwable e) {
     String className = sender;
     String message = e.getMessage();
     append(sender, message);
   }

   private static void append(String classname, String message) {
     // append something to your file
   }
}
```

You may want to add the timestamp and some line number information, which is available from `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[n]` (play with the values for n until you find the frame from the calling method, it's 2, 3 or 4)

Then, whenever you handle an exception, do

```
catch(SomeException e) {
   MyLogger.log(this, e);
}
```